# pnotify failed to close

Tags: jquery, pnotify

i am using [pnotify](http://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/) it is a great plugin, just it keep failing to close. Below is my code, i can close the notification most time, but after a while it simply fails and the closer button disappear.

```
function send_msg(status,heading,message) {
    var notice=new PNotify({
        title: heading,
        text: message,
        type: status,
        buttons: {
            sticker: false
        }
    });
}
send_msg("success","Success","Successfully added");
```

Comment: have you checked browser console window for any errors it might be throwing?

Comment: strange, there is no error

Comment: can you show it? If its running on your live site?